# How to freeze a partition of table that's moved from SSD1 to SDD2

Tags: clickhouse

I want to freeze partition of table belong schema moved from SSD1 to SSD2. I don't configure clickhouse on SSD2. When I try to freeze a partition, I caught excetion:

```
Code: 424. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, 127.0.0.1. DB::ErrnoException. DB::ErrnoException: Cannot link /data/SSD1/clickhouse/data/default/delivery_fplay_parsing/201910_831277_855321_36/PLACEMENT_NAME.mrk to /data/SSD1/clickhouse/shadow/1/data/default/delivery_fplay_parsing/201910_831277_855321_36/PLACEMENT_NAME.mrk, errno: 18, strerror: Invalid cross-device link.
```

How can I set up SSD2 to fix this error ?

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Did you moved it manually (symlinks)? You can symlink shadow folder then.

Comment: Yes, I moved it manually. As your advice, I will symlink shadow folder on SSD2. However, do I need to install clickhouse on SSD2 same SSD1? Because I only wanted to SSD2 storing data (not install clickhouse) and SSD1 installed clickhouse. Can you can describe more clearly? Thanks your ideas!

Comment: No you don't need to install CH. Ch instance in your case don't suspect that it works with 2 different filesystems. And that's why you need to symlink shadow because CH makes hardlinks with freeze and shadow & data folders both should be at one same filesystem. Try a new feature  https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-multiple-volumes in this feature will be 2 shadow folders.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks so much for your instructions, @DenisZhuravlev.